# Magento 2.0.2 - File permissions for new files

Tags: magento, centos, magento2

I am using CentOS 6.7 and I'm trying to get Magento installed on the server. All the software is the correct versions for Magento to run.

During set-up, I have followed Magento's instructions here:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/apache-user.html

The web host user and group is "nobody", so I used that in place of "apache". However, when I tried these:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html

The user I created for Magento is not permitted to run those commands.

I attempted installation anyway, it somewhat works, but new files created with Magento do not have the correct permissions. Running the Magento cleanup tool, it fixes the permissions for new files, but it would be an extremely slow process and magento is constantly creating new files.

Is there something I missed, or could there be something else causing these issues?

Comment: Magento doesn't have a good answer for that. If you look at GitHub issues or maybe elsewhere on stackexchange or stackoverflow, you might be able to find a hack. Web server running as `nobody` effectively gets no rights to anything, I forget the exact reason why.